# Forbidden Error on get_thing_shadow with boto3, aws iot and alexa

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, aws-iot, zappa

I am running a custom alexa skill with flask-ask that connects to aws iot.
Using same credentials work when running the script on local machine and using ngrok to assign to Alexa skill endpoint. But when I use zappa to upload as lambda, I get the following:

```
File "/var/task/main.py", line 48, in get_shadow
res=client.get_thing_shadow(thingName="test_light")
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 253, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 543, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
ClientError: An error occurred (ForbiddenException) when calling the GetThingShadow operation: Forbidden
```

When using ngrok, the skill works completely fine. What am I missing here? Help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was VPC access. I had to provide the role the VPC access policy and it worked.